# AWS Quicksight copying analysis / template from one region to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to copy my QS analysis from one region to another (within my account). Could you please advice how you did it or point me to relevant documentation?

I used API to create my analysis template but not sure how can I copy it to another region.

I found this tutorial explaining how to move it between different accounts but cannot find anything discussing moving between region within the same account:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/quicksight-cross-account-template/

I don't have much experience with QS so any suggestions will be much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution in this case is to re-trace your steps using the API to create a new copy in the second region. This assumes

1. the JSON description of the analysis/template from the create step still exists
2. that the analysis was not modified within Quicksight's UI in the meantime
3. that you modify any ARNs and dataset references between one region and another
4. that the dataset/datasource exists in the new region